# app actions: work with test tool but not with voice

Tags: android, android-studio, app-actions

I am exploring the app actions. I'd like to build a demo with three pages, and the user could navigate to different pages by giving the right instruction to google assistant. here is my actions.xml and AndroidManifest.xml:

```
//actions.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<actions>
 <action intentName="actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE">
    <parameter name="feature">
      <entity-set-reference entitySetId="FeatureEntitySet" />
    </parameter>
    <fulfillment
        fulfillmentMode="actions.fulfillment.DEEPLINK"
        urlTemplate="http://example.com/open{?title}">
      <parameter-mapping
          intentParameter="feature"
          urlParameter="title"
          entityMatchRequired="true"/>
    </fulfillment>
  </action>

  <entity-set entitySetId="FeatureEntitySet">
    <entity name="game" identifier="game" />
    <entity name="navigation" identifier="navigation" />
    <entity name="ebook" identifier="ebook" />
  </entity-set>
</actions>

//AndroidManifest.xml

<activity android:name="com.appactiont.demo.MainActivity"
    android:exported="true">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>

  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>

  <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true" tools:targetApi="m">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data
        android:host="example.com"
        android:scheme="http" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

It works with app actions test tool, but google assistant cannot correctly interpret "open demo game" or "open demo with feature game" (even I type it). It just opens a search result. Not sure if I missed something in my code. Appreciated if anyone can help!

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed by now. Please try it and let me know if it's working or not. Thanks!